# Pass a parameter to SVG <defs> <g>

Tags: html, svg, parameter-passing, reusability

I want to re-use the group inside < defs>. But I need to pass the image url from < use> to the < Image> inside < defs>. How to do that. I tried many ways, but didn't work.

```
<defs>
    <g  id="frame" >
      <rect  width = '200' height = '200' />
      <image href= ""/>
        </g>
  </defs>

  <use *ngFor = "let data in dataList" xlink:href = "#frame" [attr.x] = "1000" [attr.y] = "400" [attr.href] = "data.img"  transform = "scale(0.5 0.5)" transform-origin = "1100 500"/>
```

Comment: just use an image directly rather than trying this <use> <defs> <image> dance. i.e. replace the <use> element with an <image> element.

Comment: I need whole block of rect and image to be reused.

Comment: except you don't because it's different images. So create multiple rect and image elements as you need them.

Comment: This is not possible. It is limited what you can do with `<use>` and this is not one of them.